# Javascript setInterval function does not call function

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I was trying to make an image rotate in time after it got loaded, but it seemed that setInterval wasn't working properly. Therefore, I replaced the original function with test() in order to see if that worked.

Now, I would have expected that test() would be called ten times,

but test() wouldn't get called, even once.

I'd been struggling to find out the answer, in vain...

and searched through stock overflow, but all the problems seemed

irrelevant to the phenomenon I was experiencing.

I would really appreciate it if some code-guru can explain to me what is going on!

```
var testnum=0;
var testTimer;

function test()
{
  alert(testnum);

  if(++testnum>10)
      clearInterval(testTimer);
}

function r_help2(rot_obj)
{
    //rot_obj.rotTimer = setInterval( function(){r_helper(rot_obj);}, 20);

    testTimer = setInterval(function(){test()},20);
}

function rotate(name, x,y)
{
var rot_obj={angle:0,lim:180};
rot_obj.img = new Image();
rot_obj.x = x;
rot_obj.y = y;
rot_obj.img.src = "rot_"+name+".png"; //rot_1.png, ...etc
rot_obj.img.addEventListener("load",function(){r_help2(rot_obj);});
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `r_help2`? What do you see in the console?

Comment: r_help2 gets called without problem when the image gets loaded. When I look at the debugger, it seems to just ignore the timer & callback function and end execution, without any error message.

Comment: I followed the code flow line by line, and it executes r_help2. Sorry if that caused confusion. I put alert in for extra certainty.

Comment: What do you mean by _followed the code line by line_. Are you saying you've put breakpoint on every line?

Comment: No, on IE debugger I could walk through code line by line without necessarily putting a breakpoint on every line.

Comment: This works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/czo7255u/ I think r_help2 is just never called in your code for some other reason. This has nothing to do with setInterval.

Comment: @FelipeBrahm is right. If you put `alert('bla bla')` inside the `r_help2` function you'd see that it won't show up.

Comment: I put alert("r_help2()")  inside r_help2 and the message popped up.... since Felipe's code is working without problem, I don't know why this one is not working.